# change an instance variable from another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to change the instance variable of my sub class in my main class. I'm currently working on a custom button. I would like to dynamically change the border radius with the help of a ttk.Scale. But I can't find a way to influence the instance variable.

My Main Class:

```
class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
[...]
# ttk scale
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure("TScale", background=self.containerFrm.cget("bg"))

        self.scaleWidget = ttk.Scale(self.containerFrm, command=self.showScale, from_=0, to=100, length=200)
        self.scaleWidget.pack()
[...]
# the custom button:
        self.btn = CButton(self.containerFrm, width=200, height=200, radius=10)
        self.btn.place(x=0, y=0)
[...]
    def showScale(self, val):
        self.btn.configure(radius=self.scaleWidget.get()) # here is the major problem, this variable couldn't be found (unknown option)
```

Here is the second class:

```
class CButton(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, bg=None, fg="#0099ff", width=150, height=50, text="Button", borderwidth=1, radius=5,
                 bordercolor="#0099ff", hovercolor="#0099ff",
                 font=("Unispace", 12), command=None,
                 *args, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, parent, highlightthickness=0, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent
        self.widgetBg = self.parent.cget("bg")
        self.bg = bg
        self.fg = fg
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text
        self.borderwidth =  borderwidth
        self.radius = radius
        self.bordercolor = bordercolor
        self.hovercolor = hovercolor
        self.font = font
        self.function = command
```

Is there a chance to change this value: `radius` dynamicly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, `radius` isn't a widget option, it's just a normal class instance variable. To set it, you set it like you would do any other variable:

```
self.btn.radius = self.scaleWidget.get()
```

That won't cause the widget to update, however, since the widget doesn't know anything about instance variables. The better solution would be to add a method on the custom button to set the scale, so you can do something like:

```
self.btn.set_radius(self.scaleWidget.get())
```

Then, inside of `set_radius` you can both set the radius and force the button to be redrawn.

Another option would be to create a custom `configure` method that looks for non-standard options and handles them specially.

Comment: ok, thank you. it works now. i had to add two more attributes and the redraw in the set method.